# User Registration Assign to Specific Group

Tags: user, form, registration, user-groups

Joomla 3.9.14

I have a URL `example.com/training/register`, this displays a default Joomla user registration form.

Within Joomla I have various user groups;

```
 - Guest
 - Registered
 - - Training
 - - Sport
 - - Finance
 - Administrator
```

When a user registers on my site at `example.com/training/register` how can I automatically add them to the `Training` user group?

In the future I'll also need to do the same thing for other user groups and URLs, e.g;

- Register at URL `example.com/sport/register` > Add to group `Sport`
- Register at URL `example.com/finance/register` > Add to group `Finance`

Maybe I could use the Joomla User Profile plugin with a custom field that displays a dropdown of available categories (Training / Sport / Finance). Based on this selection the user would be added to the corresponding group?

I'm also open to suggestions for third party extensions.

Comment: Hey Jonboy! Briefly, these are your main options: 1. Write a custom user registration component, 2. Write a User Plugin that will handle the usergroup of the registered users, 3. Use 3rd party Form extensions which integrate with JUsers and create your custom form(s) (RSForm pro with its JUser/Registration plugin, or Fabrik are both good options for what you are after).

Comment: Some possibly helpful links: [RSForm - Custom user registration forms](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/plugins-and-modules/rsformpro-joomla-user-registration-plugin.html), [Joomla Docs Plugin/Events/User](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User), [RSForm -  dynamic user group](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/create-a-joomla-registration-form-with-dynamic-user-group-assignment.html), https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22751, https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/

Comment: I am posting the above 2 comments as an answer. If you have a moment, after completing your task, remember to come back and post your final solution as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, these are your main options:

1. Write a custom user registration component
2. Write a User Plugin that will handle the usergroup of the registered users
3. Use 3rd party Form extensions which integrate with JUsers and create your custom form(s)
   A few form extensions that work well for this use case:

   - [RSForm pro](https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html) with its JUser/Registration plugin,
   - [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/)

A few more links that can be of help:

- [Joomla Docs Plugin/Events/User](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User)
- [RSForm - Custom user registration forms](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/plugins-and-modules/rsformpro-joomla-user-registration-plugin.html)
- [RSForm -  dynamic user group](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/create-a-joomla-registration-form-with-dynamic-user-group-assignment.html)

JSE Links:

- [Assign user to a specific group based on custom field selected](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22751)
- [Pre select user group based on menu item being viewed](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/)